# clear "content" of a div on browser resizing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, computer-science

I have three divs

```
 <div class="col-md-4">
    Some content #1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-1></div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
    Some content #2
 </div>
```

col-md-4 contains a google map.
col-md-6 contains an enquiry form.
col-md-1 is blank.

css for col-md-1 is

```
.col-md-1{
    background: #fff;   
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent);
    background-position: 65%;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 1px auto;
    padding-top: 400px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This creates a separator betweeen col-md-4 and col-md-6.

The separator must be visible in desktop browsers. But on browser resizing(below 768px) the separator should be gone i.e. invisible.

In desktop browser, the website will be in this manner.

```
[          ] | [            ]
[          ] | [            ]
[google map] | [enquiry form]
[          ] | [            ]
[          ] | [            ]
```

In mobile/table browser, the website should be in this manner.

```
[google map]

[enquiry form]
```

Just the blank space between google map and enquiry form.

But I am seeing this:

```
[google map]
|
|
|
|
|
[enquiry form]
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the newest version of Bootstrap, you can add `d-none d-sm-block` classes to you `col-md-1` div.

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    Some content #1
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-1 d-none d-sm-block"></div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
    Some content #2
 </div>
```

Comment: @Aman Devrath No, if you are using Bootstrap 3, u can use `hidden-xs` instead. U can read here if u r using bootstrap 3: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done in the current version of Bootstrap 4 (beta 3):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    .col-md-1{
        background: #fff;   
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #353535, transparent);
        background-position: 65%;
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-size: 1px auto;
        padding-top: 400px;
        margin-top: 45px;
        margin-left: -17px;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            google map
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 d-none d-md-block"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            enquiry form
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```